# Wayland cross compiling makefile error

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, wayland

I am trying to cross compile wayland for an arm-linux platform. During the make, I am getting following error..

```
  CC       src/scanner.o
  CC       src/connection.lo
  CC       src/wayland-util.lo
  CC       src/wayland-os.lo
  CCLD     libwayland-util.la
  CCLD     wayland-scanner
  GEN      protocol/wayland-server-protocol.h
/bin/sh: ./wayland-scanner: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [protocol/wayland-server-protocol.h] Error 126
```

Comment: `wayland-scanner` is compiled for `arm` and is trying to execute while building (on x86). Can you give more details like from where you clonned, what commands you gave to compile, and update log with `make -d` if possible

Comment: I downloaded the wayland package from freedesktop.org

command:

./configure --build=arm-linux --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=$WLD

Answer (score 0):

If you can install the Wayland package on the build system that comes with the native `wayland-scanner` binary (e.g., `libwayland-bin` on Debian/Ubuntu, `wayland-dev` on Alpine Linux, `wayland` on Arch Linux), in the latest version of Wayland (currently 1.17.0) you can use the option `--with-host-scanner` to `./configure`:

```
 ./configure --host=${target} --with-host-scanner
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to invoke the `disable-scanner` option at the autogen stage.

```
./autogen.sh --disable-scanner --build=arm-linux --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=$WLD
```